# Where do I set the password for WSS SQL account

Tags: 2007, password, central-administration

Recently I did a password reset for the sharepoint administration accounts. When trying to access the shared services administration page I get the error: "Cannot connect to the configuration database."

I can resolve this issue by changing one of the admin accounts back to its previous password, however this password needs to be changed. 
So, where do I specify the user-name and password for this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In sp2007 it is quite complicated

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838

But in sp2010 it is solved with managed accounts.

Answer (score 0):

u can change it.

go to cental admin->operations

in operations goto data configuration section->select default database server

here u can specify your username and password.